# update a json array from a real time data with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I first get a very huge json array through an api request. And then using signalR I get a smaller json array containing only the json objects that has been changed from the api data.

**What I am trying to do** is get the changed objects from the api array and update them with the new data from the signalR.
Below is the api response.

```
[
  {carID: 38697, carNumber: 5665, dispatchStatus: 2, dataVersionNr: "AAAAAAhFXtQ=", postingID: 91},
  {carID: 38753, carNumber: 5522, dispatchStatus: 0, dataVersionNr: "AAAAAAhFXtM=", postingID: 91},
  {carID: 38635, carNumber: 5830, dispatchStatus: 2, dataVersionNr: "AAAAAAhFXtI=", postingID: 91},
  {carID: 39340, carNumber: 30027, dispatchStatus: 2, dataVersionNr: "AAAAAAhFXtE=", postingID: 91},
  {carID: 39168, carNumber: 16064, dispatchStatus: 2, dataVersionNr: "AAAAAAhFXtA=", postingID: 91},
  {carID: 40107, carNumber: 5895, dispatchStatus: 0, dataVersionNr: "AAAAAAhFXs8=", postingID: 91},
  {carID: 38647, carNumber: 22185, dispatchStatus: 0, dataVersionNr: "AAAAAAhFXs4=", postingID: 91},
  {carID: 39416, carNumber: 22180, dispatchStatus: 2, dataVersionNr: "AAAAAAhFXs0=", postingID: 91}
]
```

And here is the signalR updates.

```
[
  {carID: 38697, carNumber: 5665, dispatchStatus: 1, dataVersionNr: "AAAAAAhFXtQ=", postingID: 42},
  {carID: 38753, carNumber: 5522, dispatchStatus: 3, dataVersionNr: "AAAAAAhFXtM=", postingID: 91},
]
```

The carNumber is unique.

Comment: Where's the code where you're trying to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Object.assign` method in order to update your given array. Also, use `map` method by passing a `callback` function as argument which is applied for every item from your given array.

```js
let array = [ {carID: 38697, carNumber: 5665, dispatchStatus: 2, dataVersionNr: "AAAAAAhFXtQ=", postingID: 91}, {carID: 38753, carNumber: 5522, dispatchStatus: 0, dataVersionNr: "AAAAAAhFXtM=", postingID: 91}, {carID: 38635, carNumber: 5830, dispatchStatus: 2, dataVersionNr: "AAAAAAhFXtI=", postingID: 91}, {carID: 39340, carNumber: 30027, dispatchStatus: 2, dataVersionNr: "AAAAAAhFXtE=", postingID: 91}, {carID: 39168, carNumber: 16064, dispatchStatus: 2, dataVersionNr: "AAAAAAhFXtA=", postingID: 91}, {carID: 40107, carNumber: 5895, dispatchStatus: 0, dataVersionNr: "AAAAAAhFXs8=", postingID: 91}, {carID: 38647, carNumber: 22185, dispatchStatus: 0, dataVersionNr: "AAAAAAhFXs4=", postingID: 91}, {carID: 39416, carNumber: 22180, dispatchStatus: 2, dataVersionNr: "AAAAAAhFXs0=", postingID: 91} ]

let update_array = [ {carID: 38697, carNumber: 5665, dispatchStatus: 1, dataVersionNr: "AAAAAAhFXtQ=", postingID: 42}, {carID: 38753, carNumber: 5522, dispatchStatus: 3, dataVersionNr: "AAAAAAhFXtM=", postingID: 91}, ]

array = array.map(function(item){
  var car = update_array.find(a => a.carID == item.carID);
  return car ? Object.assign(item, car) : item;
});
console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can loop through the updates and update with Object.assign:

```js
var datas = [
{carID: 38697, carNumber: 5665, dispatchStatus: 2, dataVersionNr: "AAAAAAhFXtQ=", postingID: 91},
{carID: 38753, carNumber: 5522, dispatchStatus: 0, dataVersionNr: "AAAAAAhFXtM=", postingID: 91},
{carID: 38635, carNumber: 5830, dispatchStatus: 2, dataVersionNr: "AAAAAAhFXtI=", postingID: 91},
{carID: 39340, carNumber: 30027, dispatchStatus: 2, dataVersionNr: "AAAAAAhFXtE=", postingID: 91},
{carID: 39168, carNumber: 16064, dispatchStatus: 2, dataVersionNr: "AAAAAAhFXtA=", postingID: 91},
{carID: 40107, carNumber: 5895, dispatchStatus: 0, dataVersionNr: "AAAAAAhFXs8=", postingID: 91},
{carID: 38647, carNumber: 22185, dispatchStatus: 0, dataVersionNr: "AAAAAAhFXs4=", postingID: 91},
{carID: 39416, carNumber: 22180, dispatchStatus: 2, dataVersionNr: "AAAAAAhFXs0=", postingID: 91}
];

var updates = [
{carID: 38697, carNumber: 5665, dispatchStatus: 1, dataVersionNr: "AAAAAAhFXtQ=", postingID: 42},
{carID: 38753, carNumber: 5522, dispatchStatus: 3, dataVersionNr: "AAAAAAhFXtM=", postingID: 91},
];

updates.forEach(u => {
  var found = datas.find(d => d.carID === u.carID);
  found && Object.assign(found, u);
})

console.log(datas);
```